# how to get the same value of multiple xml file then create a folder using powershell command?

Tags: powershell

sample file xml 1

```
enter code here
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <catalog>
 <book id="bk101">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>`
  <genre>Test1</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
```

sample file xml 2

```
enter code here
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <catalog>
 <book id="bk101">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Test2</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
```

Need to get the value of "GENRES" then create each folder?

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you're trying to do here?  [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) has some great tips on writing a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With  the moving files part :

```
Get-ChildItem *.xml | % { 
            [xml]$x=get-content $_ ;
            $newpath=$x.catalog.book.genre
            new-item "$newpath"-type Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
            if ( test-path "$newpath" ) {
                move-item "$_" -destination "$newpath"
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want a directory for every genre found in xml files so , if you have a book per file :

```
Get-ChildItem *.xml | % { [xml]$x=get-content $_ ;new-item $x.catalog.book.genre -type Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  }
```

Comment: Then, I need to move the files into that folder.? Please HELP.. Thanks
sample file.xml 1 ---> Test1
sample file.xml 2 ---> test2